# Stuck with mod_rewrite: redirect dynamic page

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I just converted my forum software to a new one and i got the old url structure back, except for the boardpages-numbers and the topic page-numbers

the url structure as its now:
domain.tld/topic/34-mytopicname/?pageNo=16

It has to be or redirect to the above:
domain.tld/topic/34-mytopicname/page-16

The same url structure is used on boardpages, instead of topic, its 'forum'

My htaccess looks as follows:

```
#SEO_START
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteBase /
        # Rewrite application /
        RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/topic/([0-9]+)-([^/]+)/page-([0-9]+)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/Thread/%1-%2/?pageNo=%3 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
#SEO_END
```

With that structure i get a white page when accessing the url as /page-16.

Thx.

Comment: You need to be clearer. `The same url structure is used on boardpages, instead of topic, its 'forum'` Ok but it's internally rewritten to what ? Also, your question and your last rule don't correspond: `index.php/Thread/` ??

Comment: Hi,

sorry that its not that clear: The goal is to rewrite topic/34-mytopicname/page-16 to mytopicname/pageNo=x, where X is the number.

For the forum strucure, its the following: /forum/29-Home-Theater-nieuws?pageNo=2 where the old url uses /page-2, it needs to be like the topic.

I got the code from the board devs